# How do I stop `babel-loader` for webpack from minifying class names?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have the following in my `webpack.config`

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use:
    { 
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            presets: [
                ["@babel/preset-env", { 
                    "targets": "last 1 chrome version"
                    }
                ]
            ],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I stop webpack/babel from minifying/mangling class names when built in production mode?

Comment: Babel doesn't do that, that's part of Webpack.

Comment: OK, so whats the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keep_classnames` terser option can do this, see terser [Minify options](https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options).

> `keep_classnames` (default: `undefined`) - pass `true` to prevent discarding or mangling of class names. Pass a regular expression to only keep class names matching that regex.

E.g.

`src/mock-link.js`:

```js
export class MockLink {
  toString() {
    return 'mock link'
  }
}
```

`src/app.js`:

```js
import { MockLink } from './mock-link'

const mockLink = new MockLink();
console.log(mockLink);
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        keep_classnames: true
      }
    })],
  }
};
```

`dist/bundle.js`:

```js
(()=>{"use strict";const n=new class MockLink{toString(){return"mock link"}};console.log(n)})();
```

If we set the `keep_classnames` to `false`, the output of the `dist/bundle.js`:

```js
(()=>{"use strict";const n=new class{toString(){return"mock link"}};console.log(n)})();
```

package versions:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
  "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
  "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.7",
  "typescript": "^5.0.4",
  "webpack": "^5.80.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
}
```